# How to get a smoother color blending on a 3D sphere showing the spherical harmonics?

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, color, output, textures

Here's a manipulate code to show the *spherical harmonics* mapped on an unit sphere:

```
RealY[n_, m_, theta_, phi_] := LegendreP[n, m, Cos[theta]]Cos[m phi]

Manipulate[
 If[n < 0 || n > 20 || Not[NumericQ[n]] || Not[IntegerQ[n]], n = 1];
 If[m < 0 || m > n || Not[NumericQ[m]] || Not[IntegerQ[m]], m = 0];
 SphericalPlot3D[
      1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> {40, 80},
      ColorFunction -> Function[
           {x, y, z, theta, phi, r},
           ColorData["Rainbow"][RealY[n, m, theta, phi]]
      ],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Mesh -> False,
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False,
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
 ImageSize -> {600, 600}
 ],
 {{n, 1, "\[ScriptL]"}, 0, 20, 1, ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"},
      AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}},
 {{m, 0, "m"}, 0, n, 1, ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}, AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}},
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
 FrameMargins -> None,
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, Style["Spherical Harmonics", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}
 ]
```

This code has two issues:

1. In the manipulate box, there's too much extra space around the sphere, and I'm yet unable to remove it.  The sphere should occupy all the free space inside the manipulate box (or maybe with a very small space around it).
2. For relatively high integers *n* and *m*, the texture becomes very ugly and "squared".  I would like to get some better results, i.e. a blurry or smoother texture on the sphere.  Any suggestion about this?

Preview:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**  I just found that adding the command `ViewAngle -> 0.3` fix the extra space issue.  But I'm wondering if this is the best way of fixing issue 1.  Also, using `Re[SphericalHarmonicY[n, m, theta, phi]]` makes my code a bit simpler, instead of building the spherical harmonics functions.

Comment: try also `Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe", "ShrinkWrap" -> True}` to remove the extra space around the sphere.

Comment: @kglr, it works. However, the manipulation appears to be a bit slower. I’m wondering why.  My biggest issue now is the color blending which is really ugly!

Comment: I found that adding 0.5 to the harmonic function (in the color function) helps a lot!. However, the shade is still very crude.